# github add admin to a public organization

Tags: github, github-organizations

A few weeks ago I created an organization for the company I am working there. Then added the CTO with admin access, and after that, I removed myself from the organization, so leaving it that only the CTO can have admin access.
But both of us were removed and now the organization has no members and on the organization >> people tab, I see ...

### This organization has no public members.

How I or the CTO can access to the organization again? We do not want it to be a public one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the CTO has been remove from the organization?

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for reply, before removing the CTO I was able to see CTO and myself. After removing my self I was not able to see him so my assumption was that since I was admin both of us have been removed. Finally github support team told me that CTO is the new admin.

Comment: He was not removed. As he is a non-public member, you cannot see him as you have removed yourself.